# How to set the nav ul display to none when clicked second time on the hamburger?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a responsive website in which when clicked on hamburger, displays a nav ul, but I have not been able to set the list display to none when clicked on the hamburger second time.

**HTML**

```
<div class=""container hamburger" onclick="toggleHamburger(this)" id="hamburger">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
<ul class="col-m-9 navlist" id="navlist">
    <li><a id="HTML" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a id="CSS" href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a id="JS" href="#">JS</a></li>
    <li><a id="FAQ" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a id="About" href="#">About</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleHamburger(hamburg) {
    hamburg.classList.toggle("change");
    displayNavList();
}
function displayNavList(){
    var navList = document.getElementById("navlist");
    navList.style.display = "block";
}
```

So, basically I want to know that if there is any way in JS to call another function when clicked on the hamburger second time.
See the problem on [AdiCodes](https://adityak1121.github.io/AdiCodes/), with the hamburger, it can open the nav list but cannot close it.

Comment: You didn't take any action to call another function 2nd time

Comment: use counter, when counter = 2, call your another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want to achieve ? or did I misunderstand the question ?

```js
var hamburger = document.querySelector('#hamburger'),
navList = document.querySelector('#navlist');


var toggleNav = function() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('js-active')
  navList.classList.toggle('js-active')
}
hamburger.addEventListener('click', toggleNav)
```

```css
#hamburger {
 color: red;
}

.js-active#hamburger {
color: green;
}

#navlist {
  display: none;
}

.js-active#navlist {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container hamburger" id="hamburger">
 HAMBURGER
</div>
<ul class="col-m-9 navlist" id="navlist">
    <li><a id="HTML" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a id="CSS" href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a id="JS" href="#">JS</a></li>
    <li><a id="FAQ" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a id="About" href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you also explain me the use of query selector code of JS, because I am new to JS?

Comment: sure, it permits you to target a dom element based on his css selector, in this case you could also use document.getElementById('navlist')

If you need to target more than one element, you can also use `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global counter

```
var count = 0;
```

The first time you click it will show your nav, and the second time it will toggle.

```js
var count = 0;
function toggleHamburger(hamburg) {
    if(count >= 1){
      var navList = document.getElementById("navlist");
      navList.style.display = "none";
    }else{
      hamburg.classList.toggle("change");
      displayNavList();
    }
    count ++;
}
function displayNavList(){
    var navList = document.getElementById("navlist");
    navList.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="container hamburger" onclick="toggleHamburger(this)" id="hamburger">
    <div class="bar1">test</div>
    <div class="bar2">test</div>
    <div class="bar3">test</div>
</div>
<ul class="col-m-9 navlist" id="navlist" style="display: none;">
    <li><a id="HTML" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a id="CSS" href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a id="JS" href="#">JS</a></li>
    <li><a id="FAQ" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a id="About" href="#">About</a></li>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, this make it do nothing the first time you click, show it the second time you click, and do nothing for every subsequent time you click.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you show/hide your list with a class, then you can toggle that class in your click handler too:

```js
function toggleHamburger(hamburg) {
    hamburg.classList.toggle("change");
    var navList = document.getElementById("navlist");
    navList.classList.toggle("shown");
}
```

With the CSS:

```css
#navlist:not(.shown) {
    display: none;
}
```